# Xcode, default window layouts?

Tags: xcode, default, preferences

No-one has been able to answer this question.

It would seem to be impossible to have XCode **open** this way.

However Youssef provided the most useful answer - so Youssef gets the points, thank you Youssef.

---

Note for future readers .. the mac utility Moom is excellent for some, but not all, problems of this nature. Again it is not a total solution.

---

Using the current up-to-date XCode,

Whenever I OPEN a project in XCode (or start a new project),

it looks like this:

[image]

However, I want it to look like this:

[image]

Again that's when I OPEN a project.

Is there any way to achieve this?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Press the buttons indicated with arrows.  Next!

Comment: Heh!  How to make that the default when it opens?

Comment: Yeah I was being facetious, even though it did answer your question.  The only way to do stuff like that in Xcode is using its *Behaviours*, however there doesn't appear to be a default Behaviour that would be appropriate to do this...

Comment: yes, Behaviours are totally unrelated here.  that's enough clutter thanks as let's try it now with a bounty.

Comment: Are you talking about the layout when creating a new project or when you open XCode in general? Did you already look for some keys in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist ?

Comment: Just a curious question. Is this issue so critical for you to put 500 bounty on it? I mean it only takes 3 clicks to do it manually

Comment: @Blub ..  Yes, the layout WHEN OPENING XCode.  For example.  Imagine you have a project in a folder on your desktop.  XCode is not running.  You have been emailed the project by a colleague, so it is a fresh project and there is nothing one can set in there. You double-click Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj and XCode opens and indeed opens the project.  I want the window/panels to be as I describe in that situation. (indeed regarding a new project yes I would want the identical behavior, by default)  Regarding the preferences files, I appreciate the tip, can you earn 500 from it ?!

Comment: @yous .. what is it with this question and clutter?  :)  Yes it is worth 500 points.  Note that I clicked "500 points" so, fairly obviously, it is worth 500 points.  Note that 500 points is nothing, i've never offered less than 500 points.  (notice my score)  Also it is a completely silly feature of the site that 500 is the max.  Again thanks for the clutter ;-)

Comment: @JoeBlow understood. I edited my answer now, not sure if you like it, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to Xcode (in the top menu bar) --> Preferences...

Switch to the **Behaviors** tab and modify what you want in the **Running** section

You'll get something like this:
[image]

You can choose to show/hide what you need, and specify the default behavior

Cheers

**EDIT:**

After understanding what you need, I will modify my answer.

There is no way to force XCode to automatically enter a behavior at startup.

The best you can do is to create a custom behavior and give it a keyboard shortcut. And when you start XCode just use the keyboard shortcut to enter the desired behavior.

This is how it is done:

In the behaviors tab (above) click on the + sign at the bottom

[image: tut1]

Then enter the desired name of this behavior (Maybe StartupBehavior)
[image: tut2]

Click on the left button to modify the shortcut key. My preferred shortcut key is **Command** + **`** (the button to the left of the '1' key). This is because it will not override any other command and it is easy to click.

Note: you can specify any shortcut you like and dont be afraid to override one that already exists if you don't use it.

Now you need to configure your behavior the way you like it

[image: Tut4]
Close the preference windows.

Now everytime you start XCode just use the shortcut key you specified (**Command** + **`** in my case) to quickly load your behavior

Note:

If you dont like keyboard shortcuts you can also load your behavior by going to **Xcode** (menu bar) --> **Behaviors** --> Select your behavior
[image: Tut5]

That is the quickest way you can achieve what you want. I dont think you will be able to force Xcode to run your behavior automatically on startup.

Hope it helped.

Cheers

Comment: hi and thanks.  I did exactly what you say using the **Running .. Start** selection.  In fact, when I **RUN** a project, it does perfectly change to the state I describe (my image 2).  HOWEVER when I first OPEN a project (or, start a new project), it does NOT go to the state I describe (my image 2).  It continues to go to the default state (my image 1).  Pls let me know if I forgot something. I notice you say "and specify the default behavior," dd you mean when you OPEN a project (or, new project) -- that is what I am looking for.  If I missed something pls tell me, thanks!

Comment: Ah you mean when you open XCode? Doesn't it automatically restore your last configuration? do you want it to use the default everytime (and not what you had when you closed it?)

Comment: @JoeBlow I edited my answer. Please check it and let me know if it helped

Comment: "There is no way to force XCode to automatically enter a behavior at startup."  if that is correct I guess that is the end of it, and you have supplied all the info.  Let's leave it for a day perhaps someone else knows how to do it by changing a preference file, editing a nib or something..  thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

1. *(not really default layout, you have to hit at least 2 keys simultaneously once XCode is open)* You could set up a behavior for "Build->Starts" and hit "CMD + B"
   after opening XCode / any Project.  This way it will 1. change to your
   Layout even if there are any errors and Build fails and 2. you don't
   have to Stop it again.

   *As already said, it's not a default layout, but I like to let the compiler run through projects of other people at the beginning anyway.*

   [image: XCode Preferences]

   ---
2. You could search for some Keys in XCodes preference file in
   `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist` as already suggested in
   my comment, I'm not experienced enough to know which are the right
   ones, sorry.

   ---
3. Wrap the .xcodeproj File opening in an application. E.g. in no way "clean", but anyway:

   1. Set up an XCode behavior like in option 1
   2. Open Automator, choose Application, drag "open Finder Items" and "run AppleScript" inside.
      [image: Automator]

      > ```
      > on run {input, parameters}
      >
      > set frontmostAppName to name of (info for (path to frontmost application))
      > repeat while frontmostAppName is not "XCode.app"
      >     set frontmostAppName to name of (info for (path to frontmost application))
      >     delay 0.5
      > end repeat
      > try
      >     tell application "System Events" to keystroke "b" using {command down} --simulates CMD + B
      > end try
      > return input
      >
      > end run
      > ```
   3. Insert some applescript like the above and save the Automator application.
   4. RightClick -> getInfo on any .xcodeproj File in Finder/on Desktop, in "open with" select your new Automator app, click add and back in the info panel -> check "Change All"

      ---

You can obviously create a new Behavior instead of using Build->starts, assign a different Hotkey in XCode and script e.g.  `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "i" using {command down, control down, shift down, alt down}` , optimize the applescript somehow or do everything via a real cocoa app if you want

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may be able to approach it using preconfigured xcuserstate files nested in your project templates' default workspace directory, but that is going to be a pain to tweak and maintain. I'm not even sure it would work.

I would personally just approach it by using Behaviors.

So:

- 1) create a Behavior
- 2) Give it a convenient key binding
- 3) Then define the Behavior. For example:

ASCII Behavior Editor:

> ```
> ...
>
> √ Show *Debugger* with *Console View*
>
> √ *Hide* utilities
>
> ...
> ```

That should do it. Just hit the assigned key command when you want to restore that display state, regardless of its initial state.

Of course, you can do a few other things or all sorts of arbitrary stuff by running an external AppleScript (triggered with a Behavior's run script facility).

Comment: Hi Justin.  I'm afraid I don't understand your answer.  I am incredibly stupid. My IQ is like 25.  For the 500 points you would have to click edit and type: "Do this _ _ click this _ _ do that _ _ type this _ _ It will now always behave at all times as you specify in the images." (If you include any other options, possibilities, discussion etc I will utterly fail to understand what you mean man.) You have so many points I doubt you would be bothered to do this!!  Thanks anyways

Comment: I have figured out what you mean about making a KEYSTROKE BEHAVIOR.  I really appreciate that info.  However ideally what I want is to change the default layout of the window (when it opens).  Note that Youssef has perfectly explained how to do it WHEN YOU HIT RUN.  That's awesome, but I just want the default layout to be that way (any time I OPEN a project).  Thanks again for the awesome behavior-keystroke tip.